# Image to MPEG on Linux works, same code on Android = green video

Tags: android, ffmpeg

**EDIT**
I have check the execution and found that the error is not (yet) at the swscale point. My current issue is that the JPG image is not found:
`No such file or directory`
when doing the `avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, imageFileName, NULL, NULL);`
Before you tell me I need to register anything, I can tell I already did (I updated the code below).
I also added the Android permission to access the external storage (I don't think it is related to Android since I can already write to the /mnt/sdcard/ where the image is also located)
**END EDIT**

I have been through several tutorials (including the few posted from SO, i.e. http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/, how to compile ffmpeg for Android...,been through dolphin-player source code). Here is what I have:
. Compiled ffmpeg for android
. Ran basic tutorials using NDK to create a dummy video on my android device
. been able to generate a MPEG2 video from images on Ubuntu using a modified version of dummy video code above and a lot of Googling
. running the new code on Android device gives a green screen video (duration 1 sec whatever the number of frames I encode)

I saw another post about iPhone in a similar situation that mentioned the ARM processor optimization could be the culprit. I tried a few ldextra-flags (-arch armv7-a and similar) to no success.

I include at the end the code that loads the image. Is there something different to do on Android than on linux? Is my ffmpeg build not correct for Android video encoding?

```
void copyFrame(AVCodecContext *destContext, AVFrame* dest,
            AVCodecContext *srcContext, AVFrame* source) {
struct SwsContext *swsContext;
swsContext = sws_getContext(srcContext->width, srcContext->height, srcContext->pix_fmt,
                destContext->width, destContext->height, destContext->pix_fmt,
                SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
sws_scale(swsContext, source->data, source->linesize, 0, srcContext->height, dest->data, dest->linesize);
sws_freeContext(swsContext);
}

int loadFromFile(const char* imageFileName, AVFrame* realPicture, AVCodecContext* videoContext) {
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
avcodec_register_all();
av_register_all();

int ret = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, imageFileName, NULL, NULL);
if (ret != 0) {
    // ERROR hapening here
    // Can't open image file. Use strerror(AVERROR(ret))) for details
    return ERR_CANNOT_OPEN_IMAGE;
}

AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx;

pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[0]->codec;
pCodecCtx->width = W_VIDEO;
pCodecCtx->height = H_VIDEO;
pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

// Find the decoder for the video stream
AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
if (!pCodec) {
    // Codec not found
    return ERR_CODEC_NOT_FOUND;
}

// Open codec
if (avcodec_open(pCodecCtx, pCodec) < 0) {
    // Could not open codec
    return ERR_CANNOT_OPEN_CODEC;
}

// 
AVFrame *pFrame;

pFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();

if (!pFrame) {
    // Can't allocate memory for AVFrame
    return ERR_CANNOT_ALLOC_MEM;
}

int frameFinished;
int numBytes;

// Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
numBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(numBytes * sizeof (uint8_t));

avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) pFrame, buffer, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
AVPacket packet;
int res = 0;
while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {
    if (packet.stream_index != 0)
        continue;

    ret = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
    if (ret > 0) {
        // now, load the useful info into realPicture
        copyFrame(videoContext, realPicture, pCodecCtx, pFrame);
        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&packet);
        return 0;
    } else {
        // Error decoding frame. Use strerror(AVERROR(ret))) for details
        res = ERR_DECODE_FRAME;
    }
}
av_free(pFrame);

// close codec
avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

// Close the image file
av_close_input_file(pFormatCtx);

return res;
}
```

Some ./configure options:
`--extra-cflags="-O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -marm -march=armv7-a -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE"`

`--extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog"`

`--arch=armv7-a --enable-armv5te --enable-armv6 --enable-armvfp --enable-memalign-hack`

Comment: Not yet. I think there is definitely some issue with decoding the JPEG to YUVJ420 or something. Though it works from linux, on Android there is something different.

Comment: Do you know the arm device architecture? I mean if neon is not supported and you are compiling for neon?

Comment: I am using the Nexus One which is a amrv7 arch. I updated some build options in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is actually working. I tried on other devices (Samsung Galaxy Tab 7) and it is fine. The issue could be due to the cyanomodgen or specific Android version.

Answer (score 1):

some links to github 'android-ffmpeg'...

https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

https://github.com/rowntreerob/android-ffmpeg

CLI instructions for using single pics or set of pics to make a mpeg...

http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f

So, if you need to output mpeg / mp4 from jpg input then its not so complicated as to require that you get way down into all the detailed method calls in libavcodec or wherever.

you can simply build ffmpeg to android executable using NDK and using toolchain and then test the CLI expressions on a rooted phone and then , if they work, use a wrapper lib in your real android app to simply call ffmpeg.main as explained in the guardian project.

you have to diddle around with how ffmpeg.main exit() is called but its a very minor tweek.

there  is lots of threads on SO regarding CLI type calls in android-ffmpeg .

unless you really need low level stuff, i do not see the benefit of getting involved with that code in an android implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I had already checked the first link and currently playing around the build scripts. I think there is something specific on the Nexus One that I need to figure out. Opening the video with the same code works, only picture can't seem to work. I will probably go with the CLI version if I really can't figure it out. This project is mostly educative for me to get my hands really dirty and clean them up with a successful build :)